# Owl sync carousel sizing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to restyle owl carousel for [synced carousel demo](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html). The 2 problems I can't figure out is how to size photos properly.

#### Issues:

1. Thumbnail. If I use images of different width and height there appear huge gaps between them, the only way to manipulate the width i have found in sync.js on line 15 `items : 15,` where you can set number of items you would like to see in the row.
2. Main photo. By default plugin shows you single item per slide in same file on line 7 `singleItem : enable` if you change it to false, you will be able to see a lot of images, but problem is that every image covers the previous one, as a result of small width. Here is a with a result I am talking about.

**P.S:** I had some problems with upload all of that to fiddle, because of some addiniotn .js files, so I've uploaded this small bunch of files. I will very appreciate if you will dedicate some time and help me figure out this unpleasant issue.

**Links:**

1. Photo with issue: postimg.org/image/dnrzgdevt/
2. Source file: filedropper.com/owlsync